# Can Alolan Pokémon evolve to non-Alolan or vice versa?

Tags: pokemon

If I have a regular Ninetales in my hand and an Alolan Vulpix on my bench, can I evolve the Alolan Vulpix into the regular Ninetales?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Alolan and non-Alolan forms are not interchangeable because they have different "names"

The [2017 Pokemon Trading Card Game Rules](https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/pdf/trading-card-game/rulebook/sm2_rulebook_en.pdf) in the section *What does and doesn't count for a Pokémon's name?* makes it clear that the Alolan and non-Alolan versions are not the same Pokémon.

> An owner or form name in a Pokémon’s name is part of the Pokémon’s name:
>
> - Meowth, Alolan Meowth, and Rocket’s Meowth have different names

There are other rules for what counts as the same or a different name, but for our purposes, "Alolan X" is not the same name as "X".

### The "evolves from" name must exactly match the name of the pre-evolutionary Pokémon

From the same section:

> When evolving, the “evolves from” Pokémon name must match the Pokémon being evolved. So Graveler can evolve from Geodude, or
>   Geodude LV. 12, but not Brock’s Geodude.

The "evolves from" Pokémon is referring to the Pokémon in the upper left corner of an evolutionary Pokémon.

### Alolan Pokémon follow these same rules

Consider [Alolan Persian](https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-tcg/pokemon-cards/sm-series/sm1/79/):

[image: Alolan Persian]

Alolan Persian's card says in the upper left corner "Evolves from [Alolan Meowth](https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-tcg/pokemon-cards/sm-series/sm1/78/)". Since "Meowth" is treated as a different name, you cannot evolve a Meowth into an Alolan Persian. This is reiterated in Appendix K of the rules:

> Note that “Alolan” is part of the Pokémon’s name—this means that Alolan Persian can only evolve from Alolan Meowth, not from Meowth. Also, you can have up to 4 Persian and up to 4 Alolan Persian in your deck if you wish.

There are some circumstances where a non-Alolan Pokémon can evolve into an Alolan Pokémon, such as [Alolan Raichu](https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-tcg/pokemon-cards/sm-series/sm4/31/).

[image: Alolan Raichu]

In this case, the upper left corner of the card explicitly says "Evolves from Pikachu", thus a regular Pikachu will work (but not something like [Surfing Pikachu](https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-tcg/pokemon-cards/platinum-series/pl2/114/), as fitting as that might be).

In your particular case, Ninetales' card says that it evolves from "Vulpix". Since "Alolan Vulpix" is considered to be a different name, it cannot evolve into Ninetales. Similarly, an Alolan Ninetales' card would say that it evolves from "Alolan Vulpix", so "Vulpix" cannot evolve into it.